# Wordpress: Special css for TWO Pages

Tags: php, css, wordpress

In my blog i have two sites, that need a special css. For the site "projects" i did this:

```
 <?php if ( is_page('projects') ) { ?>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/projects.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<?php } else { ?>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<?php } ?>
```

This works like a charm.. but i also need a special css for the home..
How can i do that..? if i just put:

```
<?php if( is_home() ) { ?>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/home.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<?php } ?>
```

Above the other code, it will not work..

The whole code i use now is:

```
<?php if( is_home() ) { ?>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/home.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<?php } ?>


        <?php if ( is_page('projects') ) { ?>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/projects.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <?php } else { ?>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <?php } ?>
```

Thanks for your help - and sorry for my english !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do:

```
<?php if(is_front_page()) { ?>
       // html code here
      <?php } else if ( is_page('projects')) { ?>
        // html code here 
      <?php } else { ?>
        // html code here
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: thanky you.. but i get a blank page when using: <?php if(is_front_page()) { 
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/home.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
      } else if ( is_page('projects') ) {
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/projects.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
      } else {
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  } ?>

Comment: you should be mindful of closing and opening <?php ?>

Comment: you owe me one! :) heh, j/k